# How to debug XSL in Intellij? URI http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java does not identify an external Java class

Tags: xml, xslt, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a XSL in Intellij and I am getting this exception:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The URI http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java does not identify an external Java class
    at com.icl.saxon.style.StyleElement.styleError(StyleElement.java:818)
    at com.icl.saxon.style.XSLStyleSheet.process(XSLStyleSheet.java:626)
    at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1121)
    at com.icl.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:994)
    at org.intellij.plugins.xsltDebugger.rt.engine.local.LocalDebugger$1.run(LocalDebugger.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I run instead of debug I get this:

```
[ERROR]: Could not compile stylesheet
[FATAL]: Cannot convert data-type 'java.util.Calendar' to 'reference'.
```

Is there something wrong with the XSL or my set up?

Answer (score 0):

You're using Saxon 6.x, which is a pretty strange choice nowadays as it was superseded about 14 years ago, and it only supports XSLT 1.0 whereas XSLT 2.0 (supported in current Saxon releases) is much more powerful.

I suspect that the actual problem is that your stylesheet contains calls to Java code using the calling conventions from Xalan. Calling from XSLT to Java is not compatible across XSLT processors.

Although I use IntelliJ all the time, I've never used it for XSLT development so I can't advise you how to select a different XSLT processor.